# wget on Debian Server gets 302 Found while wget on Manjaro gets 200 OK

Tags: https, debian, wget

I'm using wget to retrieve the Instagram JSON from the URL https://www.instagram.com/instagram/?__a=1.

Running wget from my local Manjaro setup returns a `200 OK` and the proper JSON response, but running it from a Debian server retrieves a `302 found`.

At first I thought it could be because of the wget version differences, but running curl locally also works while wget doesn't work properly.

Is there anything that I should be setting up on my server to get a proper response? My guess is that the HTTPS connection is refusing my server from connecting properly.

Comment: By loading the URL in Chrome and copying the cURL request and running it on the server I was able to get  the proper response, but this seems more like a workaround?

Comment: Very interesting. Please try running Wget with the `--debug` switch and share the output. I'm keen to see what the differences are

Comment: @darnir Didn't know about the `--debug` argument! I've ran the command on both systems: https://pastebin.com/1FiAuVER https://pastebin.com/q53u03ju

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this is a weird quirk of the Instagram servers. Nothing you can do about it.

The problem is that Instagram responds differently depending on whether you connect to their server over IPv4 or IPv6. Why they would do that is beyond me, but I can reliably reproduce the result by controlling for only this variable.

IPv4:

```
$ wget -O/dev/null -4 "https://www.instagram.com/instagram/?__a=1"                                                          
--2020-09-03 14:22:15--  https://www.instagram.com/instagram/?__a=1
Resolving www.instagram.com (www.instagram.com)... 157.240.27.174
Connecting to www.instagram.com (www.instagram.com)|157.240.27.174|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 118552 (116K) [application/json]
Saving to: ‘/dev/null’

100%[================================================================================================================================>] 118,552      306KB/s   in 0.4s   

2020-09-03 14:22:17 (306 KB/s) - ‘/dev/null’ saved [118552/118552]
```

IPv6:

```
$ wget -O/dev/null -6 "https://www.instagram.com/instagram/?__a=1"                                                          
--2020-09-03 14:22:54--  https://www.instagram.com/instagram/?__a=1
Resolving www.instagram.com (www.instagram.com)... 2a03:2880:f23f:e5:face:b00c:0:4420
Connecting to www.instagram.com (www.instagram.com)|2a03:2880:f23f:e5:face:b00c:0:4420|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Cookie coming from www.instagram.com attempted to set domain to www.instagram.com
Cookie coming from www.instagram.com attempted to set domain to www.instagram.com
Location: https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=/instagram/%3F__a%3D1 [following]
--2020-09-03 14:22:54--  https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=/instagram/%3F__a%3D1
Reusing existing connection to [www.instagram.com]:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Cookie coming from www.instagram.com attempted to set domain to www.instagram.com
Cookie coming from www.instagram.com attempted to set domain to www.instagram.com
Length: 48094 (47K) [text/html]
Saving to: ‘/dev/null’

100%[================================================================================================================================>] 48,094      --.-K/s   in 0.04s   

2020-09-03 14:22:54 (1.28 MB/s) - ‘/dev/null’ saved [48094/48094]
```

This is the same thing you see in your debug logs. On Manjaro, it makes a IPv4 connection, while on Debian it makes a IPv6 connection leading to the differences.
Welcome to the world of crazy webservers :)

In any case, the answer to your question then is to use only a IPv4 connection